# Are the Skeleton Traps permanent?

Tags: clash-of-clans

After the release of the Halloween Update for **Clash of Clans**, I noticed a new trap (the Skeleton Trap) had been created. The cost to upgrade them is pretty expensive (*600,000 gold is insane*), so is there any information regarding the duration of the Skeleton Trap?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah they are permanent and will stay for ever and are not only for the halloween, also the cost to upgade is actually considerable cuz the traps act like cc troops and every upgrade brings in another added skeleton